# ssh not recognized as a command when executed from python using subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, subprocess

This is my code -

```
import subprocess
import sys

HOST="xyz3511.uhc.com"
# Ports are handled in ~/.ssh/config since we use OpenSSH
COMMAND="uptime"

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                       shell=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print (sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error)
else:
    print (result)
```

and this is the error I'm getting-

> ERROR:
>   [b"'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\n",
>   b'operable program or batch file.\r\n'].

Not sure what I'm doing wrong over here. Also, I haven't mentioned any port. All I want is to use subprocess and connect to remote server, execute a simple command like `ls`. Python version is 3.x.

Comment: are you able to ssh explicitely on terminal? I mean not in Python program

Comment: Are you executing this on a Windows machine which doesn't have an SSH client (with the name `ssh`) installed?

Comment: yes I'm using this program in windows

Comment: @alfe I'm getting the same error on a windows machine with SSH installed (ssh command works in cmd but not in subprocess)

Comment: Make sure the ssh command is found.  Either set you weir Windows equivalent of the PATH variable accordingly or just use the complete path to the `ssh` executable instead of just `ssh`, i. e. something like `C:\some\path\to\ssh`.

Comment: having the same problem. With python2 works fine, ssh is reachable from cmd/powershell

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this happens in python3.
Workaround found at this link:
https://gist.github.com/bortzmeyer/1284249

```
system32 = os.path.join(os.environ['SystemRoot'], 'SysNative' if platform.architecture()[0] == '32bit' else 'System32')
ssh_path = os.path.join(system32, 'OpenSSH/ssh.exe')
out1, err1 = Popen([ssh_path, "pi@%s"%self.host, "%s"%cmd],
              shell=False,
              stdout=PIPE, 
              stderr=PIPE).communicate()
```