# SSH doesnt work inside script and give error 'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, windows, ssh, automation, scripting

I was planning to automate the manual steps to run the ssh commands using python. I developed the code that automatically executes the below command and log me in VM. The SSH command works fine whenever i run the code in spyder and conda prompt. The command works whenever I open the cmd and try the command directly where the key is, but fails and give error whenever i run  the python script on cmd prompt

```
os.system('cmd /k "ssh -i <path to private key> <user>@<remotehost>"')
```

error:

```
'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to solve this error to run the script on cmd?
Note: The ssh commands works fine in cmd but not inside script when run on cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using the actual path to the command.

Example: 
os.system('cmd /k "/usr/bin/ssh -i " @"')

That path could be different for you. 
You can type "which ssh" to find the path to ssh if you are using a Linux environment.

Comment: "where ssh" would be the Window equivalent FYI

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe  Now the error has changed to "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: C:\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe

Comment: try the above instead

Comment: Same error, it seems the cmd that script opens doesnt recognise or relsove the path. However the same path works in cmd open using win+r

Comment: Have you enabled ssh in windows? [link] (https://www.howtogeek.com/336775/how-to-enable-and-use-windows-10s-built-in-ssh-commands/)
If so can you ssh normal on cmd to the desired location?

Comment: yes, I have enabled. I can do normal ssh but not inside python script

Comment: Are you using python3?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the path to the ssh executable in your path environment variable. You can either add it to the environment variable or you could try to specify the full path to the ssh program.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra " in the middle of your example command, just after the path of the private key. Also remember you have to use two \\ in order to specify the private key path correctly. Here's an example:

```
import os
os.system('cmd /k "ssh -i C:\\Users\\dhruv\\.ssh\\id_rsa <user>@<remote_host>"')
```

Comment: my bad, I have edited the command. Thanks, the command works but the ssh is not recognised that is the problem in my code

Comment: Checkout if your problem is similar to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156884/ssh-not-recognized-as-a-command-when-executed-from-python-using-subprocess) seems somewhat the same problem, just the op is using subprocess instead of os.